# Union type with interface in signature file

Tags: f#, signature, f#-3.0

Given the following code int the implementation file:

```
namespace Lib

module Test =

    type ITest =
        abstract member IsTest: bool

    type T = Test with 
        interface ITest with
            member this.IsTest = true

    let create () = Test
```

And the following signature file:

```
namespace Lib
module Test =  

    [<Interface>]
    type ITest =
        abstract member IsTest: bool

    type T 

    val create: unit -> T
```

The following warning occurs:

Warning 2. The type implements the interface 'Test.ITest' but this is not revealed by the signature. You should list the interface in the signature, as the interface will be discoverable via dynamic type casts and/or reflection.

How should the signature of type T be changed in the signature file to conform to the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You should list the interfaces in the type definition inside the module signature (fsi) file, for example:

```
namespace Lib
module Test =  

    [<Interface>]
    type ITest =
        abstract member IsTest: bool

    type T =
        interface ITest
        //you can list other interfaces here

    val create: unit -> T
```

Note, there is no member listing when you specify the interfaces in the fsi files (we omitted the `IsTest` member when defining type `T`), the member listing should be part of the module implementation (fs) file.

#### Update

The above example is valid for F# 4.0. Since the OP tagged the question with the F#-3.0 tag, then the syntax for the older F# should be a little different -- in the fsi file instead of

```
type T = ...
```

use

```
type T with ...
```

this has to be changed as in the original example if you plan on upgrading  to F# 4+. The compiler will display the relevant warnings for this change